# Setting a 105 keys keyboard geometry under Xorg

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

The keyboard geometry on my system is set as "pc104", whilst I would like to set is as "pc105".  I have looked into `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, but I can't see anything related.

I am running Debian GNU/Linux 8.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using systemd you can find your current layout with

```
localectl status
```

which might print something like

```
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc104
     X11 Options: caps:capslock
```

Use these values when setting a new *layout [model [variant [options]]]*, eg:

```
sudo localectl set-x11-keymap us pc105 '' caps:capslock
```

This command should be needed only once.